# Printing HTML page with many columns and many rows with page break

Tags: css, html

I have a html table with many rows and colums.I am trying to rotate the page(-90) so that all columns can fit into the page when the page is print.

Page break is not working when I print the page.

Here is the code. this table just have one column and It is just an example of what I am trying to achieve.

```
<div class="rotate"><table><tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_0</td></tr>
<tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_1</td></tr>
<tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_2</td></tr>
<tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_3</td></tr>
<tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_4</td></tr>
<tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_5</td></tr>
<tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_6</td></tr>
<tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_7</td></tr>
<tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_8</td></tr>
<tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_9</td></tr>

    <tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_8</td></tr>
<tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_9</td></tr>
<div class="breaktr"></div>
<tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_0</td></tr>
    <tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_8</td></tr>
<tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_9</td></tr>
 <tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_0</td></tr>
        <tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_6</td></tr>
        <tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_7</td></tr>
        <tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_8</td></tr>
<tr><td>The_quick_brown_fox_jumped_over_the_lazy_dog_A_9</td></tr></table></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rmn3wsxb/3/

Comment: "is not working" has never helped anyone, anywhere at any time to solve an issue. _What does that mean?_ Is it printing over the paper edge? Does it swallow the missing lines? Are the following pages scrumbled? Does the universe implode? We cannot _guess_ all that. You have to tell us.

Comment: @arkaschaPlease take a look at the fiddle and I have already mentioned that page break is not working.

Comment: Sorry, what is the fiddle meant to show? It shows a table with rows. So? Try to read the question from _our_ point of view. We have no idea what you are talking about. How should we understand what _exactly_ the issue is?

Comment: You can't have divs as direct children of a `<table>`. You'll have to end the table and start a new one at that point, or apply the class to the previous `<tr>`.

Comment: @arkascha When I  print the page it just prints the last few rows that fits into a page and doesn't print all the rows.

Comment: @arkascha I am expecting rows before the div "breaktr" in a page and the rows after the div "breaktr" in another page.

Comment: @JuhanaThank you! I will modify my code as per your advise.

Comment: @JuhanaI don't want another table.I have applied the class to a tr and I just want to cause a page break before tr class "breaktr" .But it doesn't work that way , when I print the page.